# convert dateTime into Time using Only Time while binnding

Tags: datetime, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a binding value, which is DateTime DataType and I'm trying to convert it into Time only, it's in this context `Text="{Binding AppointmentDate.Value.ToString("H:mm") }"`
in the label but this is not working and gives errors, How can I convert it and use only time without touch c# file?

Comment: instead of "gives errors" it's much more helpful to actually give us the exact error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change time format this way .

```
<Label Text="{Binding AppointmentDate, StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}'}"></Label>
<Label Text="{Binding AppointmentDate, StringFormat='{}{0:hh\\:mm}'}"></Label>
```